# empty field error only first block execute

Tags: android

`public  void save_record()
     {
           name_val  = name.getText().toString();
           pass_val  = password.getText().toString();
           cpass_val = cpassword.getText().toString();`

```
      save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                if(name_val.equals(null)==true || pass_val.equals(pass_val)==true || cpass_val.equals(cpass_val)==true)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete Text Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


             }
         });
 }
```

if all fields are completed or not only first block execute... please tell me anser

Answer (score 0):

here you are using || between your conditions so if all fields are empty then

`if(name_val.equals(null)==true)` is going to be executed and if all the fields are filled then one of the other two will execute for sure because you are comparing

`pass_val.equals(pass_val)==true` and `cpass_val.equals(cpass_val)==true` which is always going to be true so check your conditions and then try